# Iphone how to take high quality screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, screenshot

I'm trying to find a solution on how to take high quality screenshots of my IOS apps. I'm putting together a portfolio of my work and i want to take screenshots of my apps and publish them on a website.

However the screenshots are in low quality, my problem is explained here : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5436152

How do you take high quality screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods

1) Click Home + Power

2) From the simulator using File -> Save Screen Shot (Command-S) or press ⌘ + S .Those files end up on the Desktop.

3) Using the Finder (command-shift-3 or command-shift-4), these also end up on the Desktop

4)And if want programmatically follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1703/_index.html)

Comment: Taking screenshots via Simulator is the best way I have found. Saves some work because if you have to take them on the device, then you have to transfer them to your computer anyway.

Comment: Yea i agree. Its more effortless.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Simulator for this.

Launch your application using the Simulator and press `⌘ + S` to save the current screen to your Desktop.